# How to split a single word using split()

Tags: python

I have a word like

```
fef2.
```

I needed only "f2"(concatenation of 3rd and 4th character) from that word. How can i extract it from the word given using split. When i see the functionality of the split, it works only when there is a delimiter. How to split if there is no delimiter in the word?

Comment: A string in python is essentially a list so you can index into it.

Comment: Just use slicing: -`"fef2"[2:]`

Comment: How about str.rpartition?  Although I would slice as other comments suggest. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> 'fef2.'[2:4]
'f2'
```

From [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> Strings can be subscripted (indexed); like in C, the first character
>   of a string has subscript (index) 0. There is no separate character
>   type; a character is simply a string of size one. Like in Icon,
>   substrings can be specified with the **slice notation**: two indices
>   separated by a colon.
>
> ```
> >>> word
> 'HelpA'
> >>> word[4]
> 'A'
> >>> word[0:2]
> 'He'
> >>> word[2:4]
> 'lp'
> ```
>
> Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to
>   zero, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being
>   sliced.
>
> ```
> >>> word[:2]    # The first two characters
> 'He'
> >>> word[2:]    # Everything except the first two characters
> 'lpA'
> ```

Comment: dst = "ff02::ef12:2345:2345:f3f4"  
temp = dst.split(':')[-1:]
temp2 = temp[2:4]  
print temp.....I should get an answer to this as f4 according to the solution. I am still getting f3f4 as output. i am using python 2.6. is this a problem of python?

Comment: @JustinCarrey `print temp2`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `split()` for this:

```
s = 'fef2.'
print(s[2:4])
```

Here, `2` is the starting index and `4` is one past the ending index. Python uses zero-based indices, so the first character's index is zero.

The `start:end` construct is called a *slice*. You can read more about slicing here: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: I'd love to see this answer include a description of what a slice is in Python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation

Comment: @bossylobster: Good idea. Link added.

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring 'fe' as the delimiter does the work.

```
'fef2'.split(sep = 'fe')
```

However, this approach can't deal with the dot at the end of the string.